# how can I use two font families in bootstrap 5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, font-family

I am building a react project with bootstrap 5, and i want to add 2 font families in the project. i have changed the defalut bootstrap font family using a ggogle font, how can i add another font family, and how can i use classes for the two fonts seperately

```
// Import Bootstrap and its default variables
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Serif+Display&display=swap');

:root{
    --bs-body-font-family:'DM Serif Display', serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to overwrite Bootstrap in that way. I found a workaround (at least for my use case) which you may find useful.

In my case I had two font families as files in my assets directory, one which I had to use for regular text and another for bold text.

You can overwrite the default font-family of Bootstrap and then use a custom CSS class to use another font-family where you need it to.

Here an example for my use case:

```
// 1. Import Bootstrap's functions
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Override default variables. Bootstrap docs: "Variable overrides must come after functions are imported, but before the rest of the imports."

// Import Fonts
@font-face {
  font-family: "First_Font_Regular";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("/assets/fonts/First_Font_Regular.woff2") format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Second_Font_Bold";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url("/assets/fonts/Second_Font_Bold.woff2") format("woff2");
}

// Override default font families
$font-family-base: 'First_Font_Regular', sans-serif;
$font-family-sans-serif: 'First_Font_Regular', sans-serif;

// It is not possible to use another font-family for bold text via Bootstrap's .fw-bold, it has to be used via a custom class

.font-bold {
  font-family: "Second_Font_Bold", sans-serif;
}

// Import rest of Bootstrap
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```